# Invoice PDF show tax multiple times

Tags: magento, pdf, invoice

(Mage 1.6.2.0)

as I want to print an invoice (pdf) it shows up the tax multiple times in the product list (that's okay) and after the costs of shipment.

In total it is shown 4 times where 2 are redundant and I want to get rid of them.
What class generates this PDF and at which places do I change it's behaviour of showing taxes?

Answer (score 1):

I guess, that the full tax summary for the is enabled and may be you don't need to override any classes to remove the 2 redundant rows.

For the experiment, can you do the next: In admin area go to System -> Configuration -> Tax

Now in the group "Orders, Invoices, Creditmemos Display Settings" check if "Display Full Tax Summary" is set to YES. If it's set to YES change it to NO, save the configuration and try to generate the PDF again.

Share the result with us.

Answer (score 1):

In Magento there is bug when shipping tax is displayed twice. You can fix this in /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php (line 588 - magento 1.8)

```
            if ($total->canDisplay()) {
            $total->setFontSize(10);
                 // duplicate tax fix
                $duplicates = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $total->getTotalsForDisplay())));
                foreach ($duplicates as $totalData) {
                $lineBlock['lines'][] = array(
```

Comment: It is useful answer when activate Tax summary as on.. shipping tax display multiple time. I have fixed it using above code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ceckoslab your answer led me to the right configuration
I have posted my configuration on the magento community post
here: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/279846/
Cheers